# Null pointer exception while writing to textview

Tags: android

```
public class temperature extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button connect;
TextView textView;
RadioButton radioButton,radioButton2;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what) {
            case bluetooth.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                bluetooth.connectedThread = new bluetooth.ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String s = "successfully connected";
                bluetooth.connectedThread.start();
                break;
            case bluetooth.MESSAGE_READ:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0,5);

                Log.d("strIncom", strIncom);
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    //if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                    String sbprint = sb.substring(0,endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DATA WRITE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    textView.setText(strIncom + "" + "C");            // update TextVie
                    textViewTemp.setText("DATA");

                    }

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
                Date now = new Date();
                String fileName = formatter.format(now) + ".txt";//like 2016_01_12.txt
                    try
                    {
                        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Music_Folder", "Report File1");

                        if (!root.exists())
                        {
                            root.mkdirs();
                        }
                        File gpxfile = new File(root, fileName);
                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile,true);
                        writer.append("Temperature:"+strIncom+",");
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data has been written to Report File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ISSUE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            break;
        } } };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temperature);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    TextView textViewTemp  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp);
    ButtonInit();
    init();

}

void init(){
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    bluetooth.gethandler(mHandler);

}

void ButtonInit(){
    connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    connect.setOnClickListener(this);
    radioButton =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    radioButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    radioButton2 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    radioButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.BT1"));
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            if (radioButton2.isChecked()){
                if (bluetooth.connectedThread != null)
                    bluetooth.connectedThread.write("Q");
            }else{
                if (bluetooth.connectedThread != null)
                    bluetooth.connectedThread.write("E");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton:
            if (radioButton.isChecked()){
                if (bluetooth.connectedThread != null)
                    bluetooth.connectedThread.write("E");
            }else{
                if (bluetooth.connectedThread != null)
                    bluetooth.connectedThread.write("Q");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the `XML` file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.biomapp.temperature"
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:outlineProvider="background"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:contentDescription="Temperaure "
    android:clickable="false">

    <TextView android:text="@string/tempcf" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTemp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 - C/F"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTemp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="141dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONNECT"
        android:onClick="connect"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Celsius"
            android:onClick="selectTemp"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:checked="false"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fahrenheit"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I got this error

```
03-22 02:48:14.567  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-22 02:48:14.567  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
03-22 02:48:14.567  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-22 02:48:14.567  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-22 02:48:14.567  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
03-22 02:48:14.567  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
03-22 02:48:14.576  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.example.blutoothtest
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:297)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at com.lenovo.powersetting.apprestriction.CleanupService.a(CleanupService.java:158)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at com.lenovo.powersetting.apprestriction.CleanupService.a(CleanupService.java:113)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at com.lenovo.powersetting.apprestriction.CleanupService.onStartCommand(CleanupService.java:290)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3079)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:176)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1535)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
03-22 02:48:14.577  19267-19267/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code here. Are you sure you initialized the Object?

Comment: Your stacktrace is incomplete

Comment: Cannot find `nullpointerexception` in the `stacktrace`

Comment: As wvdz, your stack trace is incomplete. It should include a mention of your class `temperature`, which btw, should be `Temperature`.

Answer (score 1):

replace

`TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);`

whit

`this.tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);`

then you can you can set text like

`this.tv.setText("text")`